# rock critic and article needling Mick Jagger for whining about not getting laid enough in Satisfaction

Tags: rock

I remember reading an article ranking great songs, it might have been by Bill Wyman (journalist, not rock star) in which Satisfaction was described as Mick Jagger whining about not getting laid more than twice on a weekend.

The above is of course a paraphrase, but hopefully someone knows the article I am talking about and can give me a link.

Comment: IDK about the article. But I do know that _Mick Jagger whining about not getting laid more than twice on a weekend_ is BS, The lyrics are mostly social commentary and _I can't get no satisfaction_ is more about philosophical/existential angst than sexual frustration. The song has 3 verses, the first two of which have nothing to do with sex. 1 _When I'm drivin' in my car And a man comes on the radio_ 2 
_When I'm watchin' my TV
And a man comes on to tell me...
I can't get no satisfaction_